# Click - How to test a group that modify the context?

Tags: python, click, command-line-interface

I'm making a CLI using click.

I have a group that initiate value in context.obj :

```
@click.group()
@click.pass_context
def main(ctx):
    ctx.ensure_object(dict)
    ctx.obj["auth"] = ("username", "password")
```

How can i test this function ? Test the value added to the context

I try using `click.get_current_context` but i did not find a way to achieve what i want.